# Blank tikz figure in a pdf file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmath, pgfmathparse

This could be a very problematic post so sorry in advance.

I am trying to draw a figure using tikz for a manuscript and when I used it, the first time it worked very well. But now I have added some functions in my "command" file and since that when I run my document : no error is detected but the figure just doesn't show up : instead there is a complete blank page and I don't get why...

[image]

Here is my reduced code showing the problem :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}

\include{formatAndDefs}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\setcounter{page}{0}
\bibliographystyle{StyleThese}
\begin{vcenterpage}
\noindent\rule[2pt]{\textwidth}{0.5pt}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
scale = 0.675
]
\fill[cyan!25] plot[domain=0:8, samples=100] (\x, {gauss(\x)})|- (0,0);
\draw[very thick, orange!60]  plot[domain=0:9.5, samples=100] (\x, {gauss(\x)});
\fill[gray!25] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0) -- (9.5,0) -- (9.5,-0.5) -- (0,-0.5);
\fill[pattern = north east lines] (-0.5,-0.5) -- (0,-0.5) -- (0,4.5) -- (-0.5,4.5) -- (-0.5,-0.5);
\draw[red, dashed, thick, Stealth-Stealth] (-0.25,0) --node[fill=white,scale=0.75]{$h$} (-0.25,{gauss(0)});
\draw[red, dashed, thick, Stealth-Stealth] (0,-0.225) --node[fill=gray!25,scale=0.55]{$R$} (7,-0.27);
\draw[black, dashed, thick, Stealth-Stealth] (0,{gauss(0)}) --node[above,scale=0.65]{$L$} (7,0);
\node[below left, scale = 0.85] at (9,3) {$\boxed{\epsilon \approx \frac{L-R}{R}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\noindent\rule[2pt]{\textwidth}{0.5pt}
\end{vcenterpage}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that I am obliged to share my customized command file... Since it's important for solving the problem. The function created is shown in the "Some Gaussian functions" section of the file.

```
%!TEX root = Main.tex


%%%%%% FIRST PART%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1.3in,top=1.1in,bottom=1.1in,includefoot,includehead,headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05}

% List of abbreviations
% Do not try putting acronyms in section titles, that would cause infinite loop of pdftex compilation
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}

% My pdf code

\usepackage{ifpdf}

\graphicspath{{.}{images/}}

% Links in pdf


% Table of contents for each chapter

\usepackage[nottoc, notlof, notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{minitoc}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}                    % Fancy Header and Footer


%%% Fancy Header %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Fancy Header Style Options

\pagestyle{fancy}                       % Sets fancy header and footer
\fancyfoot{}                            % Delete current footer settings


\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}    % Page number (boldface) in left on even
% pages and right on odd pages
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\nouppercase{\leftmark}}      % Chapter in the right on even pages
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\nouppercase{\rightmark}}     % Section in the left on odd pages

\let\headruleORIG\headrule
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\color{black} \headruleORIG}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.0pt}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\arrayrulecolor{black}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhead{}
  \fancyfoot{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}


%%% Clear Header %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Clear Header Style on the Last Empty Odd pages
\makeatletter

\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else%
  \hbox{}%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%              % Empty header styles
  \newpage%
  \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}

\makeatother


\let\minitocORIG\minitoc
\renewcommand{\minitoc}{\minitocORIG \vspace{1.5em}}

\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multirow}


\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}

% centered page environment

\newenvironment{vcenterpage}
{\newpage\vspace*{\fill}\thispagestyle{empty}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
{\vspace*{\fill}}

% Hyperref code

\ifpdf
  \usepackage[pagebackref,hyperindex=true]{hyperref}
\else
  \usepackage[dvipdfm,pagebackref,hyperindex=true]{hyperref}
\fi

% nicer backref links
\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{%
\ifcase #1 %
(Non cité.)%
\or
(Cité en page~#2.)%
\else
(Cité en pages~#2.)%
\fi}
\renewcommand*{\backrefsep}{, }
\renewcommand*{\backreftwosep}{ et~}
\renewcommand*{\backreflastsep}{ et~}

% Change this to change the informations included in the pdf file

% See hyperref documentation for information on those parameters

\hypersetup
{
bookmarksopen=true,
pdftitle="Titre du manuscript",
pdfauthor="Votre nom", %auteur du document
pdfsubject="Description rapide du sujet du manuscrit", %sujet du document
%pdftoolbar=false, %barre d'outils non visible
pdfmenubar=true, %barre de menu visible
pdfhighlight=/O, %effet d'un clic sur un lien hypertexte
colorlinks=true, %couleurs sur les liens hypertextes
pdfpagemode=UseNone, %aucun mode de page
pdfpagelayout=SinglePage, %ouverture en simple page
pdffitwindow=true, %pages ouvertes entierement dans toute la fenetre
linkcolor=linkcol, %couleur des liens hypertextes internes
citecolor=citecol, %couleur des liens pour les citations
urlcolor=linkcol %couleur des liens pour les url
}


%%%%%SECOND PART%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%Geometry
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{layout}
\geometry{hmargin = 2.5cm}
 \usepackage{parskip}

 
%%%Axis
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


%%%%%%%%SPECIAL%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\doubleunderline#1{\underline{\underline{#1}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\e}{e}
\renewcommand{\textbf}[1]{\begingroup\bfseries\mathversion{bold}#1\endgroup}

%%%%%%%%Sections & Drawings
\usepackage{multicol} % Colonnes
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz, adjustbox}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, matrix, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                patterns.meta
                }


%%%%%%%%Some Gaussian functions
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{1}{
    \pgfmathparse{3*exp(-(#1/3.85)^2)}
}
% Second function
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gaussian}{2}
{%
    \pgfmathparse{(1/(#1 * sqrt(2 * pi))) * exp((-1 / 2) * (((x - #2)/#1) ^ 2))}%
}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mean}{7}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\std}{0.3}

\newcommand\encircle[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(X.base)] 
    \node (X) [draw, thick, shape=circle, inner sep=0] {\strut #1};}  

       
%%%%%%%%BOXES
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
```

I apologize in advance for this confusing setup, hope someone can still help me with this problem.

Thank you,

Comment: Are you sure it compiles without errors?

Comment: @daleif Yes.. In the shell generated while running, no error is provided / no bug

Comment: I get an error at \WarningFilter, where does that come from? Also you should probably use `\input` in the preamble for that file, not `\include`

Comment: `FrAlgorithm` and `FrAlgorithmic` are not known packages.

Comment: Please create a MWE showing your problem. Surely not all 45 packages are needed to reproduce your problem or all your custom colors. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: Are you sure your code compiles? The `silence` package seems to be missing. Also is the `FrAlgorithm` necessary to reproduce the problem? If yes, please tell us where to get it.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz and all : Thank you for your comments : I have edited the command file to reduce its length but maintain some functions that could maybe interfere with each other causing this problem. Thank you for your collaboration

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz `FrAlgorithm` is not necessary and not correlated to this problem. I have removed it

Comment: @Waxler Is `physics` related to the problem?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz No it's not

Comment: @Waxler Then please remove it. And repeat the process with all other packages.

Comment: @Waxler, where did your `\usepackage{tikz}`go ? (Ok, already addressed in the answers below ...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Space can matter. You have a spurious space in your gauss function definition:

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{1}{ %<------- here is a space (matters)
    \pgfmathparse{3*exp(-(#1/3.85)^2)} %<---- here too (probably harmless)
}
```

You should change that to

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{3*exp(-(#1/3.85)^2)}}
```

You can see what happens if you use different numbers for the samples:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{tikz,xcolor,amsmath,amssymb}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{1}{
    \pgfmathparse{3*exp(-(#1/3.85)^2)}
}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,patterns.meta}

\begin{document}
\foreach\samples in {10,20,...,100}{%
\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
%\fill[cyan!25] plot[domain=0:8, samples=100] (\x, {gauss(\x)})|- (0,0);
\draw[very thick, orange!60]  plot[domain=0:9.5, samples=\samples] (\x, {gauss(\x)});
\fill[gray!25] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0) -- (9.5,0) -- (9.5,-0.5) -- (0,-0.5);
\fill[pattern = north east lines] (-0.5,-0.5) -- (0,-0.5) -- (0,4.5) -- (-0.5,4.5) -- (-0.5,-0.5);
\draw[red, dashed, thick, Stealth-Stealth] (-0.25,0) --node[fill=white,scale=0.75]{$h$} (-0.25,{gauss(0)});
\draw[red, dashed, thick, Stealth-Stealth] (0,-0.225) --node[fill=gray!25,scale=0.55]{$R$} (7,-0.27);
\draw[black, dashed, thick, Stealth-Stealth] (0,{gauss(0)}) --node[above,scale=0.65]{$L$} (7,0);
\node[below left, scale = 0.85] at (9,3) {$\boxed{\epsilon \approx \frac{L-R}{R}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}}\par}
\end{document}
```

The spaces pill up and push your picture out of the page:

[image]

Comment: @Fischer Thank you ! I have completely forgot it... I was trying to search the problem somewhere else, turns out to be just in front of me... Thanks again for taking your time to dig into my code...

Answer (score 2):

Too long for comment, the example can be reduced to

The two first lines in the picture each causes the contents to disappear. Though I do not know why.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{tikz,xcolor,amsmath,amssymb}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{1}{
    \pgfmathparse{3*exp(-(#1/3.85)^2)}
}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,patterns.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[cyan!25] plot[domain=0:8, samples=100] (\x, {gauss(\x)})|- (0,0);
\draw[very thick, orange!60]  plot[domain=0:9.5, samples=100] (\x, {gauss(\x)});
\fill[gray!25] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0) -- (9.5,0) -- (9.5,-0.5) -- (0,-0.5);
\fill[pattern = north east lines] (-0.5,-0.5) -- (0,-0.5) -- (0,4.5) -- (-0.5,4.5) -- (-0.5,-0.5);
\draw[red, dashed, thick, Stealth-Stealth] (-0.25,0) --node[fill=white,scale=0.75]{$h$} (-0.25,{gauss(0)});
\draw[red, dashed, thick, Stealth-Stealth] (0,-0.225) --node[fill=gray!25,scale=0.55]{$R$} (7,-0.27);
\draw[black, dashed, thick, Stealth-Stealth] (0,{gauss(0)}) --node[above,scale=0.65]{$L$} (7,0);
\node[below left, scale = 0.85] at (9,3) {$\boxed{\epsilon \approx \frac{L-R}{R}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And by @hpekristiansen further down to this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}     
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{1}{     
\pgfmathparse{3*exp(-(#1/3.85)^2)} } 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\fill plot[samples=100] (\x, {gauss(\x)}); 
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1); 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 This can be reduced to: `\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{1}{
    \pgfmathparse{3*exp(-(#1/3.85)^2)}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill plot[samples=100] (\x, {gauss(\x)});
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` . Removing whitespace around `\pgfmathparse` helps or removing `samples=100`. I have no clue.

Comment: @hpekristiansen clearly a case of spurious spaces. Try out samples=10, 20 30 and so on and see how the plot wanders out of the page.